# Why my POST login request in app.js always return 404?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I try to finish a login function on my web application; however, when I enter the correct password and username already registered in my database, it always returns 404.

I want to use sessions to identify each unique user. And what I also want to know how to jump to a new webpage after login in successfully.

Here is my code in app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var dbConnectionPool = mysql.createPool({ host: 'localhost', database: 'health'});
app.use(function(req, res, next){
req.pool = dbConnectionPool;
next();
});

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
database : 'health'
});

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { secure:false }
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/page2.html', function(req, res, next) {
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
//  if (username && password) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            req.session.loggedIn = true;
            req.session.username = username;
            //res.redirect('/page4');
            res.send(req.session.username);
        } else {
            res.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
        }
        res.end();
    });

});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row h-25 align-items-center">
  <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <br>
    <form action="/page2.html" method="POST" id="f2" target="targetIfr">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
      </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Vali();">login</button>
        <div id="gSignInWrapper">
          <br/>
        <span>Sign in with:</span>
        <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
          <br/>
            <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <iframe name="targetIfr" style="display:none"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 position-relative">


    <div class="list-group position-absolute bottom-0 start-0" style="width: 100px">
      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary py-1">Register</li>
      <a  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-0" href="page3.html">user</a>
      <a  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-0" href="page7.html">manager</a>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion will appreciate!

Comment: `page2` !== `page2.html`

Comment: I just edit my code in app. post() but it still returns 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `page2.html` in both app.js post and html form action to `page2`

```
<form action="/page2" method="POST"
```

```
app.post('/page2', function(req, res, next)
```

Comment: 404 prob has been solved, thank you! But I have a new prob which is that the wrong password reacts the same as the correct one when the same username was used. And '''res.redirect('/page4');''' also generated that npm error: "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

Comment: @Jason if this answer solved the original problem in this question, you can mark it as accepted